# How to join collection in Mongodb using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I am working on mongodb join query using node.js, i have two collections and i want to join two collection and wants to populate the data.

Drinks Collection

```
[{
  "_id": "580a2f7615a0161010a23bfg",
  "name": "Pepsi",
  "createDate": "2016-10-21T15:08:27.405Z"
 }, {
  "_id": "580a2f7615a0161010bge345",
  "name": "Mirinda",
  "createDate": "2016-10-21T15:08:27.405Z"
 }, {
  "_id": "580a2f7615a0161010vbgdt5",
  "name": "Coke",
  "createDate": "2016-10-21T15:08:27.405Z"
 }, {
  "_id": "580a2f7615a0161010vb9876",
  "name": "Thums Up",
  "createDate": "2016-10-21T15:08:27.405Z"
 }, {
  "_id": "580a2f7615a0161010vbgmnk9",
  "name": "Slice",
  "createDate": "2016-10-21T15:08:27.405Z"
}]
```

Order Collection

```
[{
  "_id": "580fa9a92bb22e783b298798",
  "created_at": "2016-10-25T18:41:53.716Z",
  "tab": [{
      "created_at": "2016-10-26T00:21:33.100Z",
      "cost": 30,
      "quantity": 7,
      "name": "Mirinda"
 }]
 }, 
 {
   "_id": "580fa9a92bb22e783b29887h",
   "created_at": "2016-10-25T18:41:53.716Z",
   "tab": [{
       "created_at": "2016-10-26T00:21:33.100Z",
       "cost": 25,
       "quantity": 5,
       "name": "Pepsi"
    }]
}]
```

So i want to find the name of Order collection by joining Drinks collection.

Order Schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   tab: [{
       quantity: Number,
       cost: Number,
       name: {
          type: String
       },
       created_at: {
          type: Date
       }
    }],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

Drinks Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
utilities = require('../config/utilities');

var DrinkSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
   drinks_name: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order'    },
   name: {
     type: String
   },
   id: {
     type: String
   },
   createDate: {
     type: String
   },
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Drinks", DrinkSchema);
```

Node.js Code

```
var Drinks = require("../models/drinks"),
Orders = require("../models/orders"),
async = require('async'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.getOrdersList = function(req, res) {

   //How to Join Drinks and Orders Collection ?
   Drinks
   .find({})
   .populate('drinks_name', 'tab.name')
   .exec(function (err, result) { 
      console.log('The Drinks List is', result);
   });
}
```

Please kindly go through my above post and let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any built-in feature in MongoDB that allows for joins.

Comment: hey i guess aggregate query will work

Comment: Perform the join via code or check about mongoose references and population.

Comment: @My Chat: are you looking for populate Drink name with order find?

Comment: @My Chat : I posted answer check...

Answer (score 0):

Looks your  question is wrong... You need to get order information along with items but item name should be populate from drinks collection..

Order Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   tab: [{
      itemId:{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Drinks',
        required: true
      },
       quantity: Number,
       cost: Number,
       created_at: {
          type: Date,
          default:Date.now
       }
    }],
     created_at: {
          type: Date,
          default:Date.now
       }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

Drinks Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var DrinkSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   drinks_name: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order'},
   name: {
     type: String
   },
   createDate: {
     type: Date,
     default: Date.now
   },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Drinks", DrinkSchema);
```

~
Node Code:

```
var Drinks = require("./drinks"),
Orders = require("./orders"),
mongoose = require('mongoose');
/* mongoose.connect('mongodb://connectionsrint'); */
   //How to Join Drinks and Orders Collection ?
   Orders
   .find({_id:'582ae63967190c92552f871b'})
   .populate('tab.itemId')
   .exec(function (err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
   });
```

output

```
[{"_id":"582ae63967190c92552f871b","__v":0,"created_at":"2016-11-15T10:40:57.256Z","tab":[{"itemId":{"_id":"582ae4988bd47efe54bc5282","name":"Pepsi","__v":0,"createDate":"2016-11-15T10:34:00.115Z"},"quantity":5,"cost":125,"_id":"582ae63967190c92552f871c","created_at":"2016-11-15T10:40:57.262Z"}]}]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way you can make Joins in MongoDB, as it is a NoSQL DB. What I understand is that you want to retrieve data from 'Drinks' depending on the name field of 'Orders'. What you can do is find the 'tab.name' field for every document in your Orders collections and then find it's '_id' field from your Drinks collections.

```
Orders.find({"tab.name":"Mirinda"});
Drinks.find({"name":"Mirinda"}), { "_id" : 1", "created_at":1});
```

You can then concatenate both results and more or less get what you want.

Comment: official there is  not joins but as he using mongoose he can go with populate option.. but he is looking for populate for data type Array.

Comment: @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD hey thanks, yes i am looking for populate query can you please help me with that ?

Comment: I have been used populate but.. not tried with array object.. I will check and update you..

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  At the time this answer was posted (Nov 15 2016), `$lookup` had been in MongoDB for almost a year (since v3.2).

Answer (score -1):

Joins are not natively supported in MongoDB but we can implement joins approach in two different ways :

- Embedded Objects (embedding reference object in document itself)
- Storing _id of reference object in referring document.

If you have created a schema using mongoose ODM you can fetch the reference object using

`Drinks.find({}).populate('orders').exec(cb)`.

==============================

Here is a slight change in the schema for orders and drink. You don't need to have a cost field as it can be calculated based on the quantity for each drinks. Find the populate query too.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Orders = new Schema({
    waiter: {type: String},
    table:  {type: Number},
    items: [
        {
            quantity: {type: Number, default: 1 },
            drink_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Drinks'}
        }
    ],
    billed: false,
    timestamp : {
        createdAt: created_at,
        updatedAt: updated_at
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', Orders);


var Drink = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    cost: {type: Number, required: true}
    discount: { type: Number},
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: created_at,
        updatedAt: updated_at
    }
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Drink', Drink);


============

For Querying : 

var Orders  = require('./Orders.js');

Orders.find({}).populate('drinks').exec(function(err, documents){
    // you will get drinks object in response 
})
```

You will have to write a query for updating order if the quantity for particular in order is updated to reflect in orders and you can use aggregation framework for calculating the cost for order on particular table.

Comment: @MyChat regarding last point for updating a drinks quantity you can find using $in operator on mongo

Comment: @MyChat my bad $in won't work but $elemMatch would do this for searching in array of objects

Comment: This answer is incorrect. At the time this answer was posted (Nov 15 2016), $lookup had been in MongoDB for almost a year (since v3.2)

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("welcomedb");
  dbo.collection('orders').aggregate([
    { $lookup:
      {
        from: 'drinks',
        localField: 'tags.name',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'orderdetails'
      }
    }
  ]).toArray(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    db.close();
  });
});
```